# How to prepare an INSERT statement with a dynamic table name for the pq driver

Tags: go, pq

How do you use a dynamic table name for a prepared `INSERT` statement for the pq postgres driver? At the moment I've got a test table with `id SERIAL` and `values TEXT` columns, and this statement is failing:

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO $1(values) VALUES($2);")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

That's failing with:

> pq: syntax error at or near "$1"

If I can only use placeholders for values and not table names, is there a way around using `Sprintf` here? The table name contains a `string` from user input and although I can sanitize it it will slow down the insert a bit compared to letting Postgres return an error on an prepared statement.

Comment: Taking a table name from user input, even if you deny SQL injection by using prepared statements, is still extraordinarily dangerous - they could hit any table. If you must do this, do it using `Sprintf`, but make sure to sanitize the table name down to only those characters allowed in table names per the database's documentation.

Comment: @Adrian Noted. The table names are actually composed from a strong hash function, pre-calculated and stored in a `map`.

Comment: @AndreaM16 the question was specifically "is there a way around using Sprintf here".

Comment: You can't use placeholders for identifiers (such as table and column names). Identifiers exist at a different level than values (just like variable *names* in Go exist at a different level from values like `6`). Whitelist them and quote them (manually since there is AFAIK no "quote identifier" function in the database interface) and use `Sprintf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To substitute table name variables, go sql package doesn't yet provide a standard interface ([in progress](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18478)).

You might be able to use a database driver specific quote function, eg: [QuoteIdentifier](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#QuoteIdentifier).

See also [postgres parameter quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE) examples.